# Is D4 (the octic group) isomorphic to U(16) (group of units mod 16)?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism

I know they both have the same cardinality and are not cyclic. As well, I know that both groups have the same number of finite elements.

I know of no way to disprove that they're isomorphic, but am having a hard time finding a certain isomorphism.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What's the "octic group"? Is it non-Abelian?

Comment: It is the group of symmetries of a square. Also called a Dihedral group

Comment: Then it's non-Abelian.

Answer (score 2):

I’m pretty sure that U(16) is Abelian — it inherits commutativity from arithmetic mod 16. So U(16) and D4 are not isomorphic, since D4 is non-Abelian.

Comment: Oh right. Thank you. I was confused because I was thinking about how cyclic groups are abelian, but it isn't true in general that abelian groups must be cyclic. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: @NeilsonsMilk if you find right answer ,then try to accept it.